# Vectorizing Matlab replace array values from start to end

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization, indices

I have an array in which I want to replace values at a known set of indices with the value immediately preceding it. As an example, my array might be

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
```

and the indices of values to be replaced by previous values might be

```
y = [2, 3, 8];
```

I want this replacement to occur from left to right, or else start to finish. That is, the value at index 2 should be replaced by the value at index 1, **before** the value at index 3 is replaced by the value at index 2. The result using the arrays above should be

```
[1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0]
```

However, if I use the obvious method to achieve this in Matlab, my result is

```
>> x(y) = x(y-1)

x =

     1     1     2     4     5     6     7     7     9     0
```

Hopefully you can see that this operation was performed right to left and the value at index 3 was replaced by the value at index 2, then 2 was replaced by 1.

My question is this: Is there some way of achieving my desired result in a simple way, without brute force looping over the arrays or doing something time consuming like reversing the arrays around?

Comment: Why the desire to eliminate a loop? Because that would be the simple way. Loops have seen quite a bit of improvement with the new engine in R2015b and are not that much slower than other methods nowadays.

Comment: @ Adriaan My arrays are rather large and I can't use the latest Matlab version. Besides, I feel looping should be handled by Matlab's vectorization. They can always do it more efficiently than I could.

Comment: It's not happening right-to-left, it's just copying the values rather than propagating them. I agree with @Adriaan, a loop seems the most logical in this case.

Comment: @beaker Yes it is the most logical answer in this case, but in asking this question, I was hoping there might be a better solution. One perchance that involved a feature of Matlab that I didn't know. I try to avoid loops where possible.

Comment: @zephyr I understand, but I don't know of anything that would be applicable. Have you tried out a loop on a test data set just to see how it goes?

Comment: @beaker I have not tried looping as I know it will work and could probably do so in a reasonable time period. I'm mostly asking this question to see if there is a more elegant way that utilizes Matlab's vectorization. But I think now that is unlikely, given the way Matlab copies arrays when operating on them.

Comment: @zephyr never assume that loops are going to be slower. Write functioning code first and profile/optimize later.

Comment: I confirm that `x(y) = x(y-1)` works fine in Octave 4. Is this still broken in current Matlab? (which version?)

Comment: Anyway for Matlab, I was going to suggest reversing the index vector: `y_ = fliplr(y)` then seeing if `x(y_) = x(y_-1)` works. Equivalently, `wrev()` instead of `fliplr()`

Comment: Tagged and retitled this 'Vectorization'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, practically this is a loop but the order is number of consecutive index elements

```
while ~isequal(x(y),x(y-1))
  x(y)=x(y-1)
end
```

Comment: That's quite clever. I'd be interested to see what the performance difference is.

Comment: I like this solution. Thanks!

Comment: @beaker On my machine, a regular `for`-loop is ten times faster, which is what I expected.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Interesting!

Comment: @TroyHaskin: For what input? For the worst case, `y=2:numel(x)` this solution is slow. The runtime of this is input dependent.

Comment: @Daniel I was doing `for k = 1:numel(y)` and iterating on `x(y(k)) = x(y(k)-1);`.  Did I completely misinterpret the question?

Comment: The runtime of this answer depends not only on the size but also on the content of `y`. Compare `y=2:2:1000` and `y=2:1:500`

Comment: @Daniel And I get a performance ratio from 0.86-ish (`2:2:1000`) to 280-ish (`2:1:500`); the "ten" came from the OP which I took as representative before they indicated "rather large" arrays.  I'm not trying to debase any of the work done here; just hard-lining that a `for`-loop is the best performer for average use cases.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`nancumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14895-nancumsum) you can achieve a fully vectorized version. Nevertheless, for most cases the solution [karakfa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34009696/2732801) provided is probably one to prefer. Only for extreme cases with long sequences in `y` this code is faster.

```
c1=[0,diff(y)==1];
c1(c1==0)=nan;
shift=nancumsum(c1,2,4);
y(~isnan(shift))=y(~isnan(shift))-shift(~isnan(shift));
x(y)=x(y-1)
```